# Jenkins calling batch file on mapped drive

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, jenkins, clearcase

I have a Jenkins job that calls a batch file on a ClearCase drive (V:).

My Jenkins slave agent is running as a service using a local admin account.
The Jenkins job does the follow:

```
cleartool startview MY_VIEW
cd /d "V:\MY_VIEW\Build"
call PrepareBuild.bat
```

When I run the Jenkins job, I keep getting "Access is denied." in the Console Output when it tries to call the batch file.  However if I manually run the above in command prompt, it completes successfully.

I did not have this problem under Windows XP. Does anybody know why this is happening on Windows 7 (32-bit)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `V:\` is a virtual drive obtained with the [windows command **`subst`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst).
It is a shortcut between the root directory of your dynamic view (`M:\yourView`) and the virtual drive.
(Ie, `V:\` is not particularly linked to ClearCase. It is just a drive letter the user wishes to associate to a certain ClearCase view root directory)

However, ClearCase registers that association in the registry `HKCU/software/atria/...`.

Which means the ClearCase session run under the local admin account for Jenkins won't know about said association and the need to restore that virtual drive.

A workaround would be to make that drive permanent, using **[psubst](http://code.google.com/p/psubst/)**.
That register the drive path in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]`, and `HKLM` is accessible from all accounts.
See " [How to make SUBST mapping persistent across reboots?](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots) "

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Had a simpler solution.

Jenkins doesn't have access to folders that only the user has access to (even though its run by the user). So the folder which is getting access denied you need to set folder permission to everyone not the user